# Need help understanding the solution of: Show that there is no perfect square whose last three digits are 341.

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Show that there is no perfect square whose last three digits are 341.

Solution: Let x be any integer. Note that if $x^2$
ended with the digits 341, then we would have $$x^2 = 1000k+341$$
for some integer k, 
so $$x^2 = 1000k + 341 = 341 = 5 (mod 8)$$. We make a table of squares modulo 8.

$$ x: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7$$
$$ x^2: 0, 1, 4, 1, 0, 1, 4, 1 $$

From the table we see that
 $$x^
2 = (0, 1,4) mod 8$$ Thus $x^2$
cannot end with the digits 341.

My problem with this solution is that i do not know i am supposed to know to take mod8 of 100k+341. I tried doing it with mod 4 and I get that
$$x^2 = 1000k + 341 = 341 = 1 (mod 4)$$

but the table of mod 4 shows me that 
$$ x: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7$$
$$ x^2: 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1 $$

So in this case it would be possible that mod 4 of $x^2$ = 1

please help me clarify this in my mind

Comment: Well, you are looking for the last three digits, which means you are working mod($1000$).  Therefore you know you are looking at congruences mod($8$) and mod($125$).  Certainly makes sense to start at $8$.